# How to get only the last k elements of a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list that contains a word and the no of times it has been used. So it looks something like this -

```
[...............(u'This', 90), (u'is', 98), (u'an', 103), (u'example', 110)]
```

I want only the last k entries of this list. In the above example consider there are many entries before this and I am only interested in these last 4 entries. I want to pass them to my web page. How do I get the last k entries?

Comment: that's not a dictionary, that's a list of tuples.

Comment: In addition, if you do end up using a `dict`, don't rely on its ordering.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian - I used sorted(wordDict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)). Thanks anyways for pointing out

Answer (score 3):

Use slicing and start at a negative index:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10][-4:]
[7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10][-1:]
[10]
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10][-9:]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>>
```

If you place `[-k:]` after a sequence, it will return the last `k` items (assuming that there are at least `k` items in the sequence).

Comment: Alternatively and perhaps more intuitively, if you place `[-k:]` after a sequence, it will return the last `k` items (assuming there are at least `k` items in the sequence).

Comment: @Amber - Yea, that does sound better.  Let me reword my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in reducing your big-O time complexity, you can use heapq instead of sort for an `O(n)` solution (n = len(L))

```
import heapq
from operator import itemgetter
W = wordDict.iteritems()
m = 4
heapq.nlargest(m, W, key=itemgetter(1)) # last m items biggest to smallest
heapq.nlargest(m, W, key=itemgetter(1))[::-1] # last m items smallest to biggest
```

In Practice, you'll probably find that Python's sort is faster than the heapq until you get to really huge dictionaries, but this is just because `heapq` hasn't been tuned as much as `sorted`